# Grabbing data from separate always running go routine running process, then sending the data to html template

Tags: go, goroutine, gorouter

I am trying to create a golang web app in which it is listening for packets being broadcasted on my network, then putting the broadcasted packets neatly in a HTML table on the frontend (continuously). Here is the code I have so far. I have spend hours, but can't figure out the rest:

Below is my code for getting the packets, then putting information about the packet into a struct.

```
func PacketListener(ch chan PacketStructureslice) {
    var (
        iface       = "en0"
        snaplen     = int32(1600)
        promisc     = false
        timeout     = pcap.BlockForever
        filter      = "arp" //capture packets only from that protocol
        devFound    = false
        // packetSlice = []gopacket.Packet{}
    )

    devices, err := pcap.FindAllDevs()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    for _, device := range devices {
        if device.Name == iface {
            devFound = true
        }
    }
    if !devFound {
        log.Panicf("Device named '%s' does not exist\n", iface)
    }
    handle, err := pcap.OpenLive(iface, snaplen, promisc, timeout)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    defer handle.Close()
    if err := handle.SetBPFFilter(filter); err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }

    source := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType()) //LinkType() is the decoder to use

    for packet := range source.Packets() {
        
            view := PacketStructure{
                PacketProtocol: "ARP",
                Something: time.Now().String(),
                Number: y,
            }
            realdata.Items = append(realdata.Items, view)
            ch <- realdata
            y++
        
    }
}
```

This child struct is later going to take part in being appended to another parent struct that contains a slice of this child struct. This will result in a slice of structs, each containing information about the packet, and then in the front end, I will loop over this slice of structs creating the HTML table. You will see what I mean.

Now here are the aforementioned two structs. PacketStructSlice is a slice of the Packetstructs, in which in the above code, I keep appending the PacketStructure struct to. I am also creating channel to have the goroutine which runs the Packetlistener function send data

```
type PacketStructureslice struct {
    Items []PacketStructure
}

type PacketStructure struct {
    PacketProtocol string
    Something      string
    Number int
}

var Channels chan PacketStructureslice
```

Below is the function that executes on the API call. Don't worry about how it's called, I have a custom template cache and template model to send everything to the frontend. All I want to focus on is how I'm getting the information

```
func (m *Repository) APIcallForGettingPackets(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    go PacketListener(Channels)
    fmt.Println("Got the request")
    receiver := <-Channels
    fmt.Println(receiver) //just doing this to test

    render.RenderTemplate(w, "packets.html", &models.TemplateData{
        DataSlice: reciever.Items,
    })
}
```

The render.RenderTemplate just sends reciever.Items to the frontend. reciever.Items should contain the slice of PacketStructure structs.

Now here is the problem. Since my PacketListener function runs forever, my code is blocked by the channel request, and everything is blocked. How would I create this code so that my code gets the slice of packet datas, and sends it to the frontend. Right now since my function runs forever in the goroutine, for some reason when I call the channel, my code also runs forever. I need some way to get the goroutine listening for packets to keep appending the packet data to the slice of packet datas, and when it does that, display it on the frontend. The frontend is pretty irrelvant, but here you go:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Something</th>
    <th>Packet number</th>

  </tr>
  {{ range .DataSlice}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ .PacketProtocol }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Something }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Number }}</td>
  </tr>
  {{ end}}
</table>
```

I'm new to go-routines, as you can probably tell, but I just can't figure this out.

Thanks :)

=====================================================================

I've tried making the channel declaration inside the API call function, but that still doesn't get the result I want. However, it does make my program run as It doesn't block the API call function. Declaring the channel outside the function blocks everything

Comment: `receiver := <-Channels` will fetch the value only once. Do you want to keep fetching values here until some expected numbers of entries are there?

Comment: Another observation, you are never closing the channel that you are sending in `go PacketListener(Channels)`.

Comment: @WhiteSword Thanks for your comments. I basically just want a constant function listening for packets in the background, then appending the packet information to a slice. I want it to continuously do this.  Now that I'm thinking about it, do I actually even need channels? Is it possible for the goroutine to just append stuff to the slice, and have the main thread be effected by it too? Maybe in the goroutine, I should call a pointer to the slice I'm appending too...

Comment: Yes, the go channels are perfect use case for this. But I don't understand why you are spawning an ever-running go-routine from your http call and then expecting to receive the result from this go-routine in the same http call? Http(http/1.1) calls are not ever lasting.

Comment: @WhiteSword. Oh ok. My thinking was that when the user first goes to the "/packets" or whatever, the API call starts that goroutine. And now I'm starting to realize that whenever the user reloads the page, my API call function will probably just spawn another goroutine, breaking the whole thing. Any ideas on how I can achieve this background function to always be appending to the slice? On top of that, how can I make the frontend automatically reload to the backend. Thanks

Comment: This is a perfect case for real-time server-side streaming communication pattern, where your client creates a persistent connection with the backend, the server keeps on sending data on this connection. You can use web-sockets mechanism, or any library based on HTTP/2.0 for this.